# Maven build failure on Gitlab when using JavaFX

Tags: java, git, maven, javafx, gitlab

I am working on a Maven Java project for as school assignment. We must use Gitlab to store our work and collaborate with teammates.

Prior to this project I had not heard of Maven nor Gitlab (although I have used Git and Github on past projects), so I am not sure if I am making an obvious mistake or if I missed something essential in my research, so please be forgiving.

I am using JavaFX for GUI including a repository called JFoenix, which I added as a dependency in my pom.xml file. In my IDE (Jetbrains), the project builds and executes with no errors, all the tests pass, and everything works as expected.

However, when I commit to Gitlab, any commits fail because Maven fails to build the application in Gitlab. This is the error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /tmp/build/src/main/java/application/controllers/AppFrameController.java:[5,19] error: cannot access ActionEvent
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project OOP-Project: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /tmp/build/src/main/java/application/controllers/AppFrameController.java:[5,19] error: cannot access ActionEvent
```

Due to these errors, I believe the build is failing because Gitlab is for some reason not recognizing the JavaFX class ActionEvent. This is the corresponding code section with all of my imports in the AppFrameController class:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent; //This is the line causing the error
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
```

The first import is for a JFoenix class, and isn't triggering any errors which makes sense because JFeonix is included as a dependency. I figured that maybe the version of Java Gitlab uses doesn't include JavaFX, so I added the JavaFX library also as a dependency in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This did not solve the issue, and I am still getting the same error and build failure in Gitlab. I don't understand why this is happening, since I added JavaFX as a dependency, shouldn't my application have access to the ActionEvent class? Furthermore, pretty much every single one of my controller classes thus far all import the ActionEvent class, yet AppFrameController is the only class that gives the error on Gitlab.

Some further information:

In my IDE, the Project SDK is jdk 1.8

The language level is set at 8. I'm not sure if any of these things matter.

If anybody can explain to me why this maven build failure is happening on Gitlab, but not in my IDE, then I will be extremely appreciative.

Comment: Does your CI cache the artifacts? You might want to do a proper clean build, doing a clean checkout and re-downloading the artifacts on CI. Also do check the build log for Maven warnings, they are often related to broken dependencies.

Comment: You are running OpenJDK 8? Without OpenJFX 8? And you are adding JavaFX 11 dependencies? That won't work. You need to install openJFX 8.